# reverse regex lookup for particular string

Tags: ruby, regex

```
"very \n simple example of big"
 => return true because first occurrence moving backwards from example is \n


"very \n\t\t simple example of big" 
 => return false because first occurrence moving backwards from example is \n\t\t
```

is this possible through reverse regex lookup?

Comment: Can you elaborate? First occurance of what? If it is \n what other sequences needs to be included?

Comment: what are you trying to match? 'example' preceded by a '\n'?

Comment: @cybernate yes. first occurence of \n

@sbeam I am trying to match words that have \n before them rather than \n\t\t before them

Comment: Too bad Ruby doesn't have either [a positive or a negative lookbehind zero-width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It's be fairly striaghtforward with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what you are looking for, but if it is *"Find out whether or not the word 'example' occurs on a line that does not start with any tabs,"* then here you go:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > samples = [ "very \n simple example of big", "very \n\t\t simple example of big" ]
 => ["very \n simple example of big", "very \n\t\t simple example of big"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > samples.map{ |s| s[/^[^\t\n]+.+?example/] }
 => [" simple example", nil]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for but you can always reverse the string and match forward:

```
>> "very \n simple example of big".reverse.match(/elpmaxe[^\t]+\n/)
=> #<MatchData "elpmaxe elpmis \n">

>> "very \n\t\t simple example of big".reverse.match(/elpmaxe[^\t]+\n/)
=> nil
```

I'm not sure if this has crossed the line between clever and stupid but it works on your examples.

Comment: In this case, how is it different from `"very \n simple example of big".match(/\n[^\t]+example/)` ? You don't use lookbehind, so I don't understand why you reverse the string... Probably a good tip though.

Comment: @Kobi: I never said it was better or even good, hence the Spinal Tap reference. I reversed the string so look-behind could be replaced with look-ahead; ralph seems to be stuck on looking backwards so you reverse things and look forward, forward is more natural direction for a regex. We all seem to be fumbling about trying to figure out what ralph is really trying to do, maybe if we throw enough half random stuff against the wall something will stick.

Comment: @Kobi: In case you're not familiar with Spinal Tap: http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/This_Is_Spinal_Tap#Nigel_Tufnel

Comment: Lost on me. I only know the [11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/These_go_to_eleven) thing.

Comment: Of course, you're right. It is useful if you did something like `elpmaxe(?!.*\t\t\n)`

Answer (score 1):

I donno Ruby, hence giving the regex that I verified in Javascript:

```
/\n[^(\t+)]+ example/g
```

Comment: `[^(\t+)]` means "anything other than `(`, `)`, `+` and tab" - you can't use quantifiers inside a character class. Also, this wouldn't allow tabs anywhere in the line.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't too clear, but I think this is what you want, using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!\t\t).*example
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/DRdlscH6cO

Here I'm using `^` for start of the line (you can use `\n` if you prefer, but it wouldn't match the first line). `.` will not match another line by default, so it's also safe.
You may also want to add capturing groups, and match only a whole word:

```
^(?!\t\t)(.*)\bexample\b
```

The regex doesn't allow lines that contain `example`, and start with `\t\t`. The line can start with a single `\t`, or have `\t\t` elsewhere.